# Item id's and attachment id's that change

Tags: exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I've been struggling for months now with a random error in the ms graph api. Finally I found some sence in the whole mess, but I think there's an error in the graph api.

I've developed a multitenant outlook-addin (JS), that my clients use to store their emails and/or the attachments into a storage. I use the Office.context.mailbox.item object to fetch both the ItemId of the message and the Id's of the attachments. I send those id's off to a sevrer to do the heavy liftning of retriving the email and/or attachments, using EWS. Because the client has a choice of selecting which attachments to save, I need to send the selected attachment Id's to the server, where I retrieve the email and the attachments. However when I try to match the attachment Id's with the selected from the Outlook app they're different, and I can't find the correct attachments. This happens with random messages, with random tenants.

From what I can see from the id's for the email and the attachments, it looks like the attachment id is prefixed with the email id. Sometimes they don't match. Example:

The user select an email in the Outlook desktop client (Mac or Windows) and get this id for the email:

```
AAMkADYxNWNjMTRiLWFjYTYtNDM1OS04MTNjLThiNzM1ZWM0ZDFmZgBGAAAAAADbXpqFYshcSYLgLaL8DcdZBwDVFKe56AEMQo4qySw0u6tyAAAfj8mWAADVFKe56AEMQo4qySw0u6tyAABBmpnFAAA=
```

The attachment has this id (which DOESN'T match the email id):

```
AAMkADYxNWNjMTRiLWFjYTYtNDM1OS04MTNjLThiNzM1ZWM0ZDFmZgBGAAAAAADbXpqFYshcSYLgLaL8DcdZBwDVFKe56AEMQo4qySw0u6tyAAAAAAEJAADVFKe56AEMQo4qySw0u6tyAABBmmK4AAABEgAQAOBOPI4JZ71CuMzlk7nqfZw=
```

but when I query the EWS using the email id (I'm aware of the REST/EWS id differences), I get this id for the attachment (which DO match the email id):

```
AAMkADYxNWNjMTRiLWFjYTYtNDM1OS04MTNjLThiNzM1ZWM0ZDFmZgBGAAAAAADbXpqFYshcSYLgLaL8DcdZBwDVFKe56AEMQo4qySw0u6tyAAAfj8mWAADVFKe56AEMQo4qySw0u6tyAABBmpnFAAABEgAQAOBOPI4JZ71CuMzlk7nqfZw=
```

The funny thing is, that it works from OWA - this attahcment id is correct. This specific email has been moved, and I know that when moving files, the id changes, but shouldn't the attachment id then follow along? In EWS the id seems to have changed but not in Outlook

Comment: Could it be related to caching? I've just setup the account on another Mac and the attachment id is correct on that computer?

Comment: It's definitely related to caching in Outlook (both Mac and Windows). If I move an email to another folder, then Outlook is not updated with the new email id, which means I can't save even the email serverside, as EWS expects the new id. This is very bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used my Id-Whispering skills to look at your ids.

The first one is the id of the item itself, not an attachment on the item.  The actual PR_ENTRYID for this id is AAAAANtemoViyFxJguAtovwNx1kHANUUp7noAQxCjirJLDS7q3IAAB+PyZYAANUUp7noAQxCjirJLDS7q3IAAEGamcUAAA==

The second one is an attachment, but the parent item is different.  The PR_ENTRYID for this id is 
AAAAANtemoViyFxJguAtovwNx1kHANUUp7noAQxCjirJLDS7q3IAAAAAAQkAANUUp7noAQxCjirJLDS7q3IAAEGaYrgAAA==

Attachment id part: EADgTjyOCWe9QrjM5ZO56n2c

The third one is also an attachment, same "attachment id" part of the id, but in this case, it refers to the item in the original location.  As you can see, the PR_ENTRYID matches:
AAAAANtemoViyFxJguAtovwNx1kHANUUp7noAQxCjirJLDS7q3IAAB+PyZYAANUUp7noAQxCjirJLDS7q3IAAEGamcUAAA==

Attachment id part: EADgTjyOCWe9QrjM5ZO56n2c

So what happened here?  What it looks like is that in the second case, the item was in a different folder.  PR_ENTRYID made up of the FID (folder id) and the MID (message id).  As a result, if an item moves from one folder to another, then the id changes.  You move it back, it reverts back to its old id.  Weird, I know.

That's a good reason for Microsoft to come up with an immutable id :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Are the ids base64 encoded or somthing? I can't quite see how you derive those PR_ENTRYID and attachment ID parts.
My biggest issue is that when moving a message, the ItemId available to Office.context.mailbox.item is the old one and not the new one, which I need to fetch the message on server side

Comment: Yes, it is base64 encoded, but in this particular case I know the format because I was the one that wrote the ID parser in exchange :-) regardless, the format supports lots of different types and the layout is a function of the type it is representing. So you can't just grab a certain portion and expect it to be the entry ID. As an aside, we will be announcing a new ID that solve this problem in the next few weeks as the ID will not change when an item is moved between folders. That should solve your specific issue.

Comment: Any update on this static ID function? I'm having issues with me trying to archive an email in the background, while the client i moving the email in Outlook, thus preventing me from finding the email, due to different ID

Comment: Just curious - what happens if you add the following header to your requests?

Prefer: IdType="ImmutableId"

?

Comment: I tried to add it but it doesn't change the id. I'm a bit confused whether it's supported in api 1.0 or only beta. This link says both https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/announcing-immutable-id-for-outlook-resources-in-microsoft-graph/ but this one says only beta https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/outlook-immutable-id.md

Comment: Ill have to check whether someone added code to ignore the header for V1/V2.  When I wrote the code it was opt in for all versions.  Can you post your request headers?

Comment: I use this functionality in office.js addin in outlook, to process an email on the server, and therefore I need an immutable id, as Outlook is not always in sync with Exchange. I can only (by default) use Outlook V2 API or EWS API from the addin and if I request the message with https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{full_message_id} and the Prefer header I get back the full mutable id. However I found a new function has been implemented 'translateExchangeIds' that translate from mutable to immutable. In the addin I get an 403 error due to lack of access.

Comment: Maybe thats why the message request return mutable id. For now I try to call my server to translate the id using the graph api (as I have Application access there).

Comment: It seems that immutable ids are not supported on webhooks, although the documentation states so. I've tried both v1 and beta but it's always the mutable id, that is used in notifications

Comment: Web hooks/subscriptions/notifications, etc... should all work with ImmutableIds.  You do, however, have to set the Prefer header when you subscribe and then all notifications from that subscription should come across as Immutable.  Delta Sync is the same way.

Comment: I've cancelled all subscriptions and then subscribed with that header, and I even checked with Fiddler to confirm - both on v1 and beta endpoints - no luck. Would be nice with a confirmation - or a ms-diag header

Comment: I've also learned that the translateExchangeIds is of no use if the message with the mutable id can't be found. I was hoping that the immutable id could be deducted from the mutable id - even if the user moved the email

Comment: Will EWS support immutable ids eventually?

Comment: No, no plans to have EWS support immutable ids as it is in maintenance mode.  If you need EWS/REST interop, you should use the translateExchangeIds REST API as that will convert between the two.

Comment: Anything I can do to debug the Webhook subscription?

Comment: @BoKDamgaard - you are correct about mutable ids - if they don't exist, translateExchangeIds can't convert them.  This is an artifact of mutable ids.  In the same way, if an item moved in the mailbox, you would not be able to bind by the old mutable id to retrieve it.  That was the main driving factor behind moving to immutable ids.  Internally there is no mathematical relationship between a mutable id and immutable id.

Comment: Can you confirm that translateExgangeIds only is available on beta and if Webhook immutable ids should be available on v1?

Comment: [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4474977/david-sterling-msft) can you check to see why a wekhook with id 394a7e90-23ba-4509-9694-729efd30f6ac on tenant cd8cba11-995d-46c2-a131-0ce32f0a8de6 doesn't send immutablt ids in notification, TIA?